# copy values from a pointer to a constant object parameter

Tags: c++

So, I have two classes definitions:

```
class class1{
  char* c1_name;
  char* c1_colour;
  double c1_price;
public:
class1(const char* name, const char* colour, double price);

class class2 {
  double c2_price;
  char* c2_message;
  Class1* c2_class1;
  int c2_Count;   

public:
  class2(const class1* class, int num);
  class2(const class1* class, int num, const char* msg);
```

How can I copy the values from class1, using the pointer to it (Class1* c2_class1)?

Comment: Easiest way would be to *not* have pointers, anywhere, and then use plain initialization or assignment.

Comment: What do you want to copy? By the way, `c1_name` and `c1_colour` seem to be string, so, use std::string instead. No need to use pointer here

Comment: hmm it seems that OP asked and then auto delete himself

Comment: There's a lot of unnecessary fluff in this question. As I read it, the question boils down to: given a `class1` object, how can you access its stored data? To answer that, we would need complete class definitions (neither class definition has a closing brace, suggesting that important parts may have been left out).

Answer (score 0):

First add a public getter method to class1:

```
double getPrice() const { return c1_price; }
```

Then to copy the price, to your constructor in class2 append:

```
class2(const class1* a_class1, int num): c2_price(a_class1->getPrice()) { }
```